# Vertical Progress Scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, progress-bar, scrollbar

I am trying to make the following example of a progress scrollbar vertical:

> http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/rangeinput/scrollbar.html

I have tried for ages now and cant seem to find a way. I'm new to jquery so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Post the code that your are using, so we can tell you how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated version from comments:

http://jsfiddle.net/SKfGQ/5/

It works, but it's massively fudged.

---

<strike>It's as simple as inverting all the `width` and `height` related properties.</strike>

So, in the JavaScript, change `left` to `top`.

In the CSS, where there is a horizontal property and a vertical property, switch them.

I took the code from here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/rangeinput/scrollbar.htm

And this was the result: http://jsfiddle.net/HGUzW/

The only new CSS is at the top:

```
#scrollwrap, .slider {
    float: left
}
.slider {
    margin-left: 50px
}
```

Comment: This looks correct, but the scrolling is completely broken. I didn't try it before, sorry.

Comment: This version has the scrolling working: http://jsfiddle.net/SKfGQ/ - the JavaScript fix probably isn't great. Let me know if it works or if it doesn't.

Comment: i need it has the progress effect as before.

Comment: i need it so when you scroll down the handle the space before hand gets filled.

Comment: It turned to be more difficult than I originally thought. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/SKfGQ/4/ - but I don't like what I had to do.

Comment: that is amazing. is there anyway to start from the top? rather than the middle?

Comment: thanks mate. can I give you some money for doing this, buy you a few beers!?

Comment: You're welcome. If you could click the tick, that's enough for me.

Comment: I have no idea. I don't have one to test with. You should ask a new question. You might want to check http://www.google.com/search?q=ipad+overflow+scroll

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this plugin for jquery?
[jquery-progressbarvertical](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-progressbarvertical/)
It seems that this is the thing that you want.
Or you can have a look at the jquery plugin site itself for the [available plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/vertical-progressbar).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var heightProgress = $('.progress_bar_bg').height();
 var positionofStart = $('.progress_section').position().top
 $(window).on('scroll',function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.progress_section').position().top - $(window).height()) {
   var scrolled = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() ;
var tabminus = (scrolled - positionofStart) ;
var value = (tabminus / heightProgress) * 100;
   $('.progress').css('height', ''+value+'%')

  }
 })
```

```css
.dummy{
 height: 1200px;
}
.progress_bar_bg{
 width: 2px;
 height: 2000px;
 background-color: grey;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}
.progress{
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: red;
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class="dummy">
  
 </div>
 <div class="progress_section">
  <div class="progress_bar_bg">
   <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="dummy">
  
 </div>
 
</body>
```